# Call Two Custom Jquery Function one after another no Ajax Involved

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I am trying to call two custom functions such that function B must execute only after function A has completed it's job. Both the functions has no ajax functionality.

I tried when , then , promise none of them seemed to work for me. Here is a snippet of the two functions.

```
   $.fn.closed = function() {
        alert("animation Finised!");
        $("#home-flipper").show("slide");
        $("#home").css("background-color", "#FBFE7B");
    };

    $.fn.start = function() {
        $("#home").css("background-color", "#212121");
        $("#os-phrases > h2").lettering('words').children("span").lettering().children("span").lettering();
    };
```

Lettering Plugin

```
/*global jQuery */
/*! 
 * Lettering.JS 0.6.1
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Dave Rupert http://daverupert.com
 * Released under the WTFPL license 
 * http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
 *
 * Thanks to Paul Irish - http://paulirish.com - for the feedback.
 *
 * Date: Mon Sep 20 17:14:00 2010 -0600
 */
(function($) {
    function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
        var a = t.text().split(splitter), inject = '';
        if (a.length) {
            $(a).each(function(i, item) {
                inject += '<span class="' + klass + (i + 1) + ' show_me">' + item + '</span>' + after;
            });
            t.empty().append(inject);
        }
    }

    var methods = {
        init: function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
            });

        },
        words: function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
            });

        },
        lines: function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
                // Because it's hard to split a <br/> tag consistently across browsers,
                // (*ahem* IE *ahem*), we replaces all <br/> instances with an md5 hash 
                // (of the word "split").  If you're trying to use this plugin on that 
                // md5 hash string, it will fail because you're being ridiculous.
                injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.lettering = function(method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if (method && methods[method]) {
            return methods[ method ].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (method === 'letters' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0)); // always pass an array
        }
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering');
        return "done";
    };


})(jQuery);
```

I tried the following

```
$.when($(this).start()).then($(this).closed());
```

But this ain't the answer to the problem I am facing.
Please help me resolve it.

Comment: one way is to make the first function return a value upon completion and then test for the return value and execute the second function

Comment: `return` the command with the animation, it's a promise object and it's what `when` expects

Comment: is `lettering` an animation?

Comment: yes .. lemme paste it's code in the question..

Comment: @avrono I did try it. something like if($(this).a ==="done") { $(this).b() } .. No luck .. !

Comment: When you say "no luck" do you mean b() is not executed ? Or do you mean that a() is executed returns and then b() is executed, but this is not what you wanted ?

Comment: @avrono Both gets executed at the same time.. I know it's strange but it's true.. and thus the post...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I won't call it the perfect solution but I need to use this tweak of mine until someone else suggests me something better.

I simply used a 20 sec timeout after the call of the first function.

```
  $(this).start();
    $.doTimeout('closed', 20000, function() {
        $(this).closed();
    });
```